# SQL 2008 full text search with ORDER BY and TOP clause and no answer from the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 200 * FROM article WITH (nolock) 
WHERE CONTAINS(*,'"ram*" and "1*"')
ORDER BY article_number
```

I am getting no results returned within 10 minute. If I stop the query after a few minutes then it returns a few records.

In `article` table there are 10,000 records. The full text catalog is on `article` 4-5 fields, so it contains only 1 table.

If I don't write the `ORDER BY` or the `TOP 200` clause then it returns immediately with the correct answer.

Article table has `INDEX (Unique, clustered)` on `Article_number`.

I think it is an MS-SQL 2008 bug.

The problem also exists on SQL 2008 SP1.

I really don't understand the problem, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do a search with terms less than 3 characters in length. As a test, try searching for something else, like:

```
select top 200 * from article with (nolock) WHERE contains(,'"ram" and "king*"') order by article_number
```

Comment: But there is two word separated with and word. So it's reasonable to search like this.

Answer (score 0):

Order by makes the query slower. Does article_number has index? Try creating an index.